# extract names in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract

In my excel file column G I have names with last name + first name + middle name.
For example Tasha, William P is the sample name and Tasha is the Last name, William is the first name and P would be the middle name. I was able to pull last name by `=LEFT(G2, FIND(",", G2)-1)`, but can't tell what would be the good ways to extract middle and first name. How can extract first and middle name with excel formula?

Answer (score 1):

```
=RIGHT(G2,1)
```

for the middle initial.

```
=LEFT(G2,(FIND(",",G2,1)-1))
```

for the first name.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(G2, " ", REPT(" ", 99)),2 * 99 - 98,99))
```

for the last name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

Put it in B1 and copy over 3 columns and down the length of the data.

[image]

---

If you want to put them in order then use this:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),(CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A),1,2,0))*999+1,999))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solutions]

> **Method 1** Using LEFT+RIGHT+MID+FIND functions

First Name: `=MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1)-FIND(",",A2)-2)`

Middle Name: `=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1))`

Last Name: `=LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)` same as yours

The logic to find **First Name** is to find the position of `,(space)` and the second `(space)` and return the characters in between. The logic for **Middle Name** is to find the second `(space)` and return whatever is on the right.

> **Method 2** Using FILTERXML+SUBSTITUTE functions

First Name: `=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,",","")," ","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[2]")`

Middle Name: `=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,",","")," ","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[3]")`

Last Name: `=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,",","")," ","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[1]")`

The logic is to use **SUBSTITUTE** to convert the full name into something like the following:

`<data><a>`Last Name`</a><a>`First Name`</a><a>`Middle Name`</a></data>`

Then use **FILTERXML** to return the desired name based on its order `1, 2 or 3` within the XML script.

For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).

Answer (score 0):

When the family name is the last name and each name is separated by space
[image]

then use this Excel formula:

```
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(F14," ","|",LEN(F14)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F14," ",""))),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F14," ","|",LEN(F14)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F14," ",""))))-SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(F14," ","|",LEN(F14)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F14," ","")))))
```